# How to avoid "package does not exist" Error in Java

Tags: java, swing, import, preprocessor, package

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I'm currently making a Java Swing that executes macros for a cfd-Simulation Programm.
The problem is, that these macros should be executionable without the variables of the swing.

My current Solution is, to comment out the the specific variables, wether its for swing or standalone using, otherwise i get a "package does not exist" Error.

This is Bad, because other people must edit my code, what often leads to desaster (I'm speaking of experience).

For Example:

```
double meshsize = 2.5;
double prismsize = 0.02;

//double meshsize = Wizard.myMeshsettings.getmeshsize();
//double prismsize = Wizard.myMeshsettings.getprismsize();
```

I'm aware that java does not have a preprocessor. Also importing a dummy is not a solution, due to policy issues.

Is there a Possibility to Check if the Wizard Class is aviable and then, only then compile the part with wizard reference?

Be Polite with me, it's the first question i ask on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no, there is no way to avoid java compiler to compile whole code.

The longer answer is the following.

First, you can compile code while all classes are available but make implementation that can work even if specific class is unavailable at runtime. Use dynamic class loading for this. (Take a look on `Class.forName()` method).

Second, you can even write code that does not require speicific class at compile time. Use reflection additionally to dynamic class loading.

For example the following code fragment will compile without class `Wizard` and work correctly with or without this class:

```
try {
    Class clazz = Class.forName("Wizard");
    Field myMeshsettingsField = clazz.getDeclaredField("myMeshsettings");
    myMeshsettingsField.setAccessible(true);
    Object myMeshsettings = myMeshsettingsField.get();
    Method getmeshsize = myMeshsettings.getClass().getMethod("getmeshsize");
    double meshsize = (Double)getmeshsize.invoke(null);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("wizard is unavailable");
}
```

The BIG question is "why?"
Why do you need this? It sounds like bad design to compile code without required dependencies. I'd suggest you to give a high-level explanation of your task. Then we will probably be able to suggest you better solution.

Comment: The Problem doesn't have a higher level Explanation to it, it's due to maintainance issues, for example updates of the cfd-software, new demands of the cfd computers or new geometry inputs. If a geometry is updated, with my current design we have to copy-paste double the code as yet and we are planning to make more wizards. (talkin about 300 macros)

Comment: I think that "with my current design" is the key here. The problem *does* have higher level explanation. Your question does not contain word "geometry" but your comment does.

Comment: Your solution is pretty good so far, however the Field Class does not have a method "getMethod", therefore i dont have acces to it. Thought about going directly into the class Meshsettings, but in there the values are not initialized.....any idea how i get access of the data of myMeshSettings?

Comment: We don't have influence of these changes, those are changes of the company cd-adapco and demands of our customers, the only problem is that we don't want to change every macro twice for every change we have ;)

Comment: Take a look on edited code. Sorry, my mistake. I wrote this code directly in SO form without compiling it.

Comment: Really big Thank you, you've been a great help so far. The Problem now is that the Object Class does not have the Method "....get()" without argument. I've looked it up in the API, but i just can't find the solution. I'm sorry for my lack in java skills, we're all thermodynamic calculators in our department.